# Selenium: What ExpectedConditions should i select

Tags: java, selenium

I want to find `Select` `WebElement`:

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("gender"));
```

So in case i want to use wait with `ExpectedConditions` and then with my element `selectByVisibleText`, `selectByValue`...
What `ExpectedConditions` should i choose: `presenceOfElementLocated` or `elementToBeClickable`

Answer (score 1):

`elementToBeClickable` should fit - it waits for an element to be both visible and enabled:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement select = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gender")));

Select genderDropdown = new Select(select); 
genderDropdown.selectByVisibleText("male");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per official documentation form selenium java doc

```
presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page.
```

and

```
elementToBeClickable(By locator)
An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
```

and there they have not defined/mentioned which is better or not, both works great you are free to choose.But in my personal opinion its better to go for

```
elementToBeClickable(By locator)
```

because

```
1.sometime you will get an error in selenium = 
**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not 
clickable at point (1019, 62.5). Other element would receive the click.**
which means the element you wanted to click is present in the DOM but yet not have 
fixed position inside the DOM so your operation (click) will be performed at some other 
location.
```

so if you go with  **presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)** then you can face above error as it will only wait till the element is available in the DOM once its available it will allow other operations to operate as its clearly written in the official document you can clearly see above.

Also you can read for more options at http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html

Hope this make sense to you ,thanks